# Win32com Outlook Group Contacts

Tags: python

I am using win32com to send an email.  I can send it to an email address without a problem.  The problem is that I need to send it to a group contact list so that I don't have to constantly update the code with new contacts.

I have not been able to find very much information on the code to send to a group contact.

```
import win32com.client as win32
import re
ol = win32.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
msg = ol.CreateItem(0)
msg.GetInspector
msg.BCC = 'Test'
msg.Subject = 'Test'
bodystart = re.search("<body.*?>", msg.HTMLBody)
msg.HTMLBody = re.sub(bodystart.group(), bodystart.group()+"""Test <br><br>

<br><br><br><br> """, msg.HTMLBody)
filename_date = str(date.today())
msg.Attachments.Add(r'C:\Test.pdf')
msg.Send()
```